# Strategy for Creating Fork of Android on GitHub

Tags: android, git, github

I'm trying to create a fairly low-level change in Android source -- changing the package manger. I want to get the whole source using the repo tool described in source.android.com. I have a fork of the platform_frameworks_base project on github.

So, the question is how do I go about getting my platform_frameworks_base instead of the one provided by Android. I just want to be able to clone my own fork, create a branch in there and then push it in my own github. I can worry about pull requests to the main repo later.

Any help on the strategy/method of doing this?

p.s. My "workflow" is aimed to be similar to this: http://appanalysis.org/download.html

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I am looking to do something similar.

Comment: Well, no. For now, I'm waiting until Google provides a mirror on github. It's probable that it's going to happen.

Comment: Google has updated the mirrors on github. The workflow should work now. I will try to get this working and post an answer on the whole workflow as soon as I can.

Comment: @recluze Did you succeed in forking Android from GitHub?

Comment: @TianyangLi Yes, I did. I will post a tutorial on my site and an answer here _inshaallah_ very soon. You will probably get a ping here when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

probably a bit late :) , but for the records, you might be want to take a look into this http://www.primianotucci.com/blog/fork-android-on-github